# Berkeley DB JE - open cursor count

Tags: java, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

Is there a way to ask the API for a list of open cursors (or at least a count of the number of currently open cursors) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys over at OTN [answered](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1002616&tstart=0) this for me.

In short, no, there is no API method to get a count of open cursors.